# Render django application within TextField

Tags: python, django

I am creating an application to display articles. In my model, I have a TextField that will contain the content of the article.

Now I would like to be able to render another application within my article. Let say I have a poll application and I would like to display a poll in the middle of the article. How can I do that ?

I tried by putting a `{% render_poll 42 %}` within the post but, as expected, it just display that within the generated page.

Should I create some kind of tag (like let say `[poll=42]`) and parse it before displaying the rendered html page ? (I use the [markdown](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Markdown/2.1.1) library, maybe I could extend it.) How can I do that to stay in a nice "django friendly" way ? I want that, when in the admin panel, I can easily insert poll (or other apps) within an article.

Comment: you should look into using something like `django-cms` or similar - this will allow you to create posts/articles made up of various types of content; text, videos, custom plugins (like a poll) etc.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't really understand the `django-cms` code but `django-basic-apps` uses inlines as shown in this screencast http://www.screenr.com/8BH which seems to do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [compile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-the-template-system) the TextField string as a template. Ie.:

```
from django.db import models
from django.template import Template, Context


class YourModel(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()

    def render_body(self, context=None):
        template = Template(self.body)
        context = context or {}
        context['object'] = self
        return template.render(Context(context))
```

Then in the actual template, you could use `{{ your_model.render_body }}` rather than `{{ your_model.body }}`.

Comment: Thank you. I guess that would work but I prefer the solution of django-basic-apps with inlines (cf answer of Timmy O'Mahony) which is maybe more flexible.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. You are of course free to prefer django-basic-apps. But I'm curious about how using a few extra layers of rendering can be more flexible than directly using django template API ... What do you mean "flexible" ?

Comment: You are right, it is actually not more flexible. Let say that is a nice layer of abstraction already built I can use.